# time.sleep not working because variable is not an int

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to create a simple OS similar to MS-DOS, and I was making a timer app, however, time.sleep requires an integer and my variable is a string, yes I've tried putting int before the variable. Here's the code.

```
elif (query1 == "timer"):
    print("Enter how many seconds you want your timer to go on for.")
    timer = input()
    time.sleep(timer)
    print("Timer Done!")
```

note: elif is correct, this is just a snippet

Thank You!

Comment: `input()` returns a `str`. use `int(input())`.

Answer (score 1):

Catch a exception to fix it when user enter a string.(just int can solve your problem)

```
elif (query1 == "timer"):
    print("Enter how many seconds you want your timer to go on for.")
    while 1:
        try:
            timer = int(input())
            break
        except:
            print("Please enter a number,Try Again")
    time.sleep(timer)
    print("Timer Done!")
```

Comment: You forgot to break out of your while loop. `try`/`except`/`else: break` should do it. Also, `while True` is preferable to `while 1`, just for readability (extreme edge case performance considerations aside)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm kinda new to python so this really helps a lot!

Comment: Maybe use a float for float input too. You can sleep for 0.5 seconds.